# Best way to check if variable is part of collection of enums?

Tags: system-verilog

I'm currently trying to port some Specman code that takes certain actions based on whether a variable is part of an enumeration. In Specman the code looks something like this:

```
define COMP_STATES do_add, do_sub;
define WAIT_STATES wait_X, wait_Y;
defube RUN_STATES  run_X, run_Y;

type my_states : [
    do_add = 3'b000;
    do_sub = 3'b001;
    wait_X = 3'b010;
    wait_Y = 3'b011;
    run_X  = 3'b100;
    run_Y  = 3'b101;
] (bits:3);
```

and then later:

```
if(state in [COMP_STATES, RUN_STATES]){
    /* DO STUFF */
} else if(state in [WAIT_STATES]){
    /* DO STUFF */
}
```

I now would like to do this in SystemVerilog but have hit a little bit of a snag. My currently best approach uses arrays:

```
my_state which_state[$] = {`COMP_STATES, `RUN_STATES};
int indexes[$]  = which_state.get_index( index ) where ( index == state );
int num_indexes = indexes.size(); //If state doesn't exist in my_state then the returned array of indexes will be empty.
if(num_indexes > 0) begin /* DO STUFF */ end
```

But there has to be a more elegant and concise way? find_first_index comes to mind but I couldn't find what it would return in case no match was found.

Comment: I'm not familiar with Specman, I think you want to use `inside` ([IEEE Std 1800-2012](http://standards.ieee.org/getieee/1800/download/1800-2012.pdf) 11.4.13 _Set membership operator_). Example: `if( state inside {COMP_STATES, RUN_STATES} ) begin ... end else if(state inside {WAIT_STATE}) begin ... end`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a couple of ways you could do this. If you can depend on the encoding, then you can define your collection with a wildcard and use the wildcard equality operator or inside operator

```
let COMP_STATES = 3'b00?; // or parameter COMP_STATES = 3'b00?;
let RUN_STATES = 3'b01?; // or parameter RUN_STATES = 3'b01?;
let WAIT_STATES = 3'b10?; // or parameter WAIT_STATES = 3'b10?;

if (my_states inside {COMP_STATES,RUN_STATES})
   ...
else if (my_state ==? WAIT_STATES)
   ...
```

or you could just create an expression

```
module top;
   enum bit [2:0] {
           do_add = 3'b000,
           do_sub = 3'b001,
           wait_X = 3'b010,
           wait_Y = 3'b011,
           run_X  = 3'b100,
           run_Y  = 3'b101
          } my_states;
   let COMP_STATES = my_states inside {do_add, do_sub};
   let WAIT_STATES = my_states inside {wait_X, wait_Y};
   let RUN_STATES =  my_states inside {run_X, run_Y};

   initial repeat(20) begin
      std::randomize(my_states);
      $write (my_states.name());
      case(1)
    COMP_STATES, RUN_STATES:
      $display("=comp,run");
    WAIT_STATES:
      $display("-wait");
      endcase
   end
endmodule
```

Finally, if you were starting from scratch, I would suggest looking at *tagged unions* and their corresponding *pattern matching conditional statements*

Comment: There're no design constraints but I'd like to keep it close to the Specman original so that the people who wrote that can remain in a familiar program flow. Either way: Am I seeing it correctly, that 'inside' won't work on **define** macros and needs **parameters** instead?

Comment: What makes you think that? **define** macros work too, but I always suggest not using them except as the last resort. It introduces file order compilation issues and they are globally scoped. Much better to use **let** or a **parameter**s in a package.